# In C++ How do I template the return value to be unique from the parameter value?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, overloading

In C++ How do I template the return value to be unique from the parameter value? 
My code looks as follows - now if data type of number is int going in I want it as a double going out.

```
template <class T>
T divide(T number)
 {
    return number/10;
 }
```

in main I have this

```
 divide(5);
 divide(2.5);
```

In the case of 2.5 the value going in and out will be type double so there isn't a problem but in the case of 5 it goes in as an int but I need it to not be truncated and returned as type double.

```
template <class T, Class T1>
T1 divide(T number)
 {
    return number/10;
 }
```

That doesn't work because its looking for two parameters in the functions.

```
T1 template <class T>
T1 divide(T number)
 {
    return number/10;
 }
```

this gives me no declaration of storage class or type specifier - when I add the word class to that line before T1 I get the error message: function returns incomplete type.

Comment: Is the return *always* `double`, or does it still depend on the input (e.g., for `char` or `short` you want return to be a `float`, and for `int` or `long` you want it to return `double`?

Comment: It's not always a double, that's why I'd like to template it. I want to return the best possible fit for the specified data type.

Comment: So you need to decide (and tell us) exactly what *is* the best fit for any given input type. To help you much, we need to know what result you want and how a result is determined based on an input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thats where my question stands - the input type can be  any numerical value (maybe even a char). But the output type, the return type is different in some instances. specially in the int vs. double or int vs float etc. The idea of the template is that any numerical value can go in but a different one can be returned.

Comment: With templates you can build a mapping from input type(s) to output type(s). But, like any programming, you have to decide on what that mapping should be. The compiler can do what you tell it, but you still need to tell it what you want (and right now, it sounds to me like you don't really even *know* what you want).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most generic method is to have a helper template

```
template <typename T>
struct calc_return {
  using type = T;
};

template <class T>
typename calc_return<T>::type divide(T number)
{
   return number/10;
}
```

Now if there are exceptions to the rule, you specialize `calc_return` using whatever logic you'd like:

```
// Prior to the declaration of divide()
template <>
struct calc_return<int> {
  using type = double;
};
```

Comment: I'll be honest I'm not 100% sure, I understand what's being done here.

Comment: The idea is that `calc_return<double>::type` is just `double`, etc - but you can specialize `calc_return<int>::type` to be whatever you want.

Comment: Why do you want to do this and not just `template <class T, class RetT>` and specify the return type through the template parameter list?

Comment: @OleksijPlotnyc'kyj : because the intent is to specify the return type as the author of the template, not the user. (Think libraries)

Answer (score 6):

In this case I think you want

```
template <class T>
auto divide(T number) -> decltype(number/10.0)
{
   return number/10.0;
}
```

The compiler has a decent idea what the return type should be, if you at least divide by 10.0 instead of 10.

Or C++14 style:

```
template <class T>
auto divide(T number) // Compiler will figure it out from the return statement.
{
   return number/10.0;
}
```

Comment: `decltype` is specifying to return a type? Is it a pointer? I'm not sure how this works. IS this basically saying `auto` will be whatever the pointer returns? does that mean the contents of the function would have to follow the `decltype` in the parenthesis?

Comment: The `auto ... ->` part means that I'll declare the return type later (I do so because it depends on `number`). `decltype` is "declared type", the type of the expression `number/10.0`. Obviously that depends on `T number`. In particular, it means there's no implicit conversion in the return statement, as the return type exactly matches the return expression. If your compiler is brand new (C++14 standard), you actually don't need the `-> decltype()` part.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
template <class T, class T1>
T1 divide(T number)
{
    return ((T1)number) / 10;
}

....

double res = divide<int, double>(2);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the compiler is looking for a function header with two variables. It should have one and return one (but the return is possibly different)

Comment: @YelizavetaYR What do you mean saying that it does not work? `divide<int, double>(....)` instantiates/calls the function with parameter of type `int` and the result of type `double`.

Comment: When i tried running this code - The call to the function would look like `divide(x);` and the compiler would throw an error telling me that my parameters don't match - I am only passing one but asking for two to be returned. The issue is we only want to pass one parameter and have one return value of a different type. Sorry if my question was unclear i didn't mean to cause confusion.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Yes, if you call `divide(x)`, the compiler cannot instantiate the function. But if you call `divide<double,int>(x)`, the compiler should be happy.